# How to add links to documentation to pipeline run in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

We have a few hundred different pipelines in Azure DevOps and we have documentation about the variables and describing what the pipeline does.

Perhaps there is a way to add a link to the documentation to the pipelines run? For example here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, the pipeline was not run indeed.

If you are using YAML pipeline, just add the comments to the pipeline definition:

```
# Follow below link for more details:
# https://www.xxx.xxx

trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

[image]

Then, you can press 'Ctrl' and right-click to go to the details page.

If you are using Classic pipeline, you can add it to this place:

[image]

You cannot add custom display items where you show. If you want to see it there, you can do this:

If you are using YAML:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the YAML pipeline, be sure to follow the steps I provided above, otherwise, the variable won't show up there.

The classic pipeline is similar.

Let me know if you have more concerns.